# Serve static files with openshift and python

Tags: python, apache, openshift, static-files

I've set up [rawdog](http://offog.org/code/rawdog/) in an OpenShift application and installed the Python and cron cartridges. I get the application to serve the generated HTML, however the css stylesheet is not available.

I use the following wsgi.py file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

SERVE_FILE = os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'], 'www', 'index.html')

virtenv = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR'] + '/virtenv/'
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = open(SERVE_FILE, 'r').read()

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    httpd = make_server('localhost', 8051, application)
    # Wait for a single request, serve it and quit.
    httpd.handle_request()
```

The css file should be in the same 'folder' as index.html,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
```

The css file is in `~/app-root/repo/wsgi/static/css/style.css`.
I also have a`~/app-root/repo/wsgi/.htaccess` file that contains:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/style.css static/css/style.css  [R]
```

So far it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas on how I can make static content available on OpenShift using Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Your `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">` should probably look like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css" type="text/css">`